# Is a Covid test required before flying to the USA from the Netherlands?

Tags: usa, air-travel, covid-19

I am going to fly to ATL (Georgia) and then to IAD (VA) and go home in MD. Is a PCR test required to be able to fly to the USA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. So far, the only country from which travel to the US requires a negative COVID test is [the UK](https://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2020/s1224-CDC-to-require-negative-test.html), in an order that took effect December 28, 2020. As of this writing, the CDC has not made such an order about any other country.

**Update:** [Starting January 26, 2021](https://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2021/s0112-negative-covid-19-air-passengers.html), a negative COVID test within 3 days of boarding the plane will be required for travelers by air to the US from all countries.

Comment: Thanks. For confirmation: I have made the journey on January 2, 2021 and the Covid test was not needed as you said.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-usa-airlines-idUSKBN29420X), the US may expand Covid-19 testing for more countries.

Answer (score -3):

Check [this page](https://www.skyscanner.net/travel-restrictions?AID=12285961&PID=8159058&SID=kjcwz0bs2202mktz0531i&associateid=AFF_TRA_00014_00002&utm_source=commission%20junction&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=gl-travel-2470763-8159058&utm_content=gl-travel-12285961&_tck=b/fqwn9l6MTFqFPLF1/8ilVE0fESuLlDT8coKepLQog), enter from the Netherlands and search below for the United States.
As you can see in the Link (point 6) only passengers arriving from the UK will need a test, for the moment....

Comment: That page does appear to provide an answer, however links can break and the information may change over time. Please expand your answer to include more details from the page you link to so that your answer is self-explicit